# Mongodb text search not returning score field

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am running below aggregation query using MongoDB Realm Web JavaScript API to make requests to MongoDB cloud database:

```
const query =    [
                { $search: {
                    index: "default",
                    text: {
                        query: 'samsung 6gb',
                        path: {
                            wildcard: "*",
                        }
                    },
                },
              },
             {
               $addFields: { score: { $meta: "searchScore" } }
             }
           ]
```

The query returns the correct results. But the 'score' field is not being added to the result. Below is the screenshot of the data, taken from network tab of Browser dev tools, that is sent by Realm Web JavaScript API to Cloud MongoDB database.

[image]

If I run the above query in MongoDB web console, it correctly shows the 'score' field added to the results. I have also tried using $project operator, but it still does not show 'score' field in results.

```
{ $project: { score: { $meta: "searchScore" } },}
```

The Javascript code is shown below:

```
const productsCollection = mongoDB?.db("database").collection("products");
const products = await productsCollection.aggregate(query);
```

This is a React application and version of Realm Web api is:

```
"realm-web": "^2.0.0",
```

Can anyone please help with this? If you need more information please let me know.

Comment: Check that [`searchScore` keyword is not supported in Stable API V1](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/meta/)